# Java8 equivalent of JodaTime DateTimeFormat.shortDate()

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time, date-parsing

What is the Java8 `java.time` equivalent of

```
org.joda.time.formatDateTimeFormat.shortDate()
```

I've tried below way, but it fails to parse values such as "20/5/2016" or "20/5/16".

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct: A Joda-Time `DateTimeFormatter` (which is the type you get from `DateTimeFormat.shortDate()`) parses more leniently than a java.time `DateTimeFormatter`. In the English/New Zealand locale (`en-NZ`) `shortDate` uses the format pattern `d/MM/yy` and parses both `20/5/2016` and `20/5/16` into 2016-05-20.

I frankly find it nasty that it interprets both two-digit and four-digit years into the same year. When the format specifies two-digit year, I would have expected four digits to be an error for stricter input validation. Accepting one-digit month when the format specifies two digits is lenient too, but maybe not so dangerous and more in line with what we might expect.

java.time too uses the format pattern `d/MM/yy` (tested on jdk-11.0.3). When parsing is accepts one or two digits for day of month, but insist on two-digit month and two-digit year.

You may get the Joda-Time behaviour in java.time, but it requires you to specify the format pattern yourself:

```
    Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-NZ");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/[yyyy][yy]", loc);

    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("20/5/2016", dateFormatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("20/5/16", dateFormatter));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2016-05-20
> 2016-05-20
> ```

If you want an advanced solution that works in other locales, I am sure that you can write a piece of code that gets the format pattern from `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern` and modifies it by replacing `dd` with `d`, `MM` with `M` and any number of `y` with `[yyyy][yy]`. Then pass the modified format pattern string to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

**Edit:** I’m glad that you got something to work. In your comment you said that you used:

```
    Stream<String> shortFormPatterns = Stream.of(
            "[d][dd]/[M][MM]",
            "[d][dd]-[M][MM]",
            "[d][dd].[M][MM]",
            "[d][dd] [M][MM]",
            "[d][dd]/[M][MM]/[yyyy][yy]",
            "[d][dd]-[M][MM]-[yyyy][yy]",
            "[d][dd].[M][MM].[yyyy][yy]",
            "[d][dd] [M][MM] [yyyy][yy]");
```

1. It covers more cases that your Joda-Time formatter. Maybe that’s good. Specifically your Joda-Time formatter insists on a slash `/` between the numbers and rejects either hyphen, dot or space. Also I believe that Joda-Time would object to the year being left out completely.
2. While you do need `[yyyy][yy]`, you don’t need `[d][dd]` nor `[M][MM]`. Just `d` and `M` suffice since they also accept two digits (what happens in your code is that for example `[d]` parses either one or two digits, so `[dd]` is never used anyway).
3. If you prefer only one format pattern string, I would expect `d[/][-][.][ ]M[/][-][.][ ][yyyy][yy]` to work (except in hte cases where the year is omitted) (I haven’t tested).

Comment: Yes the ```[]``` is working great. I just use ```Stream<String> shortFormPatterns = Stream.of(
        "[d][dd]/[M][MM]",
        "[d][dd]-[M][MM]",
        "[d][dd].[M][MM]",
        "[d][dd] [M][MM]",
        "[d][dd]/[M][MM]/[yyyy][yy]",
        "[d][dd]-[M][MM]-[yyyy][yy]",
        "[d][dd].[M][MM].[yyyy][yy]",
        "[d][dd] [M][MM] [yyyy][yy]");``` Maybe more verbose than ```joda.time``` which supported more cases implicitly, but ```java.time``` is better in other areas.

Comment: Thanks, @wilmol, for following up. I had two comments. I have added them as an edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. `d[/][-][.][ ]M[/][-][.][ ][yyyy][yy]` works very well. At least for inputs like `"20/5/2016", "20/5/16", "31.12.2009", "21 3 2017", "09/02/19", "1 5 20", "09 3 16"`.

Answer (score 2):

`FormatStyle.SHORT` returns shortest format either `dd/MM/yy` or `d/M/yy` format, so you need to use pattern to get the customized format

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();   
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)));   //9/29/19
```

You can also use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` or `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` to get the iso format like `yyyy-MM-dd`, and also you can see the available formats in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));       //2019-09-29
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)); //2019-09-29
```

If you want the custom format like `yyyy/MM/dd` the use `ofPattern`

```
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"))); //2019/09/29
```

Comment: Issue is I don't know what format the input will be. It seems JodaTime ```shortDate()``` covered more cases than java.time ```FormatStyle.SHORT```.

Comment: @wilmol What cases, please? From the documentation `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)` seems equivalent to `DateTimeFormat.shortDate()`. I don’t know Joda-Time well, so I may be missing something, though.